# Microsoft's MPEG-2 demuxer filter - can I change an elementary stream pin's PID while the graph is running?

Tags: directshow, mpeg2-ts

I'm working with multi-program UDP MPEG-2 TS streams that, -unfortunately- dynamically re-map their elementary stream PIDs at random intervals. The stream is being demuxed using Microsoft's MPEG-2 demultiplexer filter.

I'm using the PSI-Parser filter (an example filter included in the DirectShow base classes) in order to react to the PAT/PMT changes.

The code is properly reacting to the change, yet I am experiencing some odd crashes (heap memory corruption) right after I remap the Demuxer pins to their new ID's. (The re-mapping is performed inside the thread that is processing graph events, while the EC_PROGRAMCHANGED message is being processed).

The crash could be due to faulty code in my part, yet I have not found any reference that tells me if changing the pin PID mapping is safe while the graph is running.

**Can anyone provide some info if this is operation is safe, and if it is not, what could I do to minimize capture disruption?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the source code for a Windows CE version of the demuxer filter. Inspecting it, indeed, **it seems that it is safe to remap a pin while the filter is running**.

I also managed to find the source of my problems with the PSI-Parser filter.

When a new transport stream is detected, or the PAT version changes, the PAT is flushed, (all programs are removed, the table is re-parsed and repopulated).
**There is a subtle bug within the `CPATProcessor::flush()` method.**

```
//
// flush
//
// flush an array of struct: m_mpeg2_program[];
// and unmap all PMT_PIDs pids, except one: PAT
BOOL CPATProcessor::flush()
{
    BOOL bResult = TRUE;
    bResult = m_pPrograms->free_programs();   // CPrograms::free_programs() call
    if(bResult == FALSE)
        return bResult;
    bResult = UnmapPmtPid();
    return bResult;
}// flush
```

Here's the `CPrograms::free_programs()` implementation.

```
_inline BOOL free_programs()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i<m_ProgramCount; i++){
            if(!HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (LPVOID) m_programs[i] ))
                return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

The problem here is that the `m_ProgramCount` member is **never cleared**. So, -apart from reporting the wrong number of programs in the table after a flush (since it is updated incrementally for each program found in the table)-, **the next time the table is flushed, it will try to release memory that was already released**.

Here's my updated version that fixes the heap corruption errors:

```
_inline BOOL free_programs()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i<m_ProgramCount; i++){
            if(!HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (LPVOID) m_programs[i] ))
                return FALSE;
        }
        m_ProgramCount = 0;  // This was missing,  next call will try to free memory twice
        return TRUE;
    }
```